# UIDatepicker Huge memory allocation

Tags: ios, nib, uidatepicker

I have 2 Uidatepickers in my controller. when this nib gets loaded, it consumes memory of about 5mb. I tried to zero-in to the problem. It seems UIdatepickers are consuming all this. If is remove them, it takes only about 0.1mb. These datepickers are static i.e. i created them by just drag and drop and assigned IBOUTLETS to them. This dosent seem to be a code issue, thus i have none to post. Please help. thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to make your own datePicker by `UIPickerView`,which will const less memory if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5mb is a reasonable amount of memory to consume on any platform, regardless of whether you're on an iPhone or iPad. If for any reason this allocation bugs you, create the `UIDatePicker`s programatically and nil them out when you're done with them so that they're released.

Comment: so u saying 5mb memory consumption is fine for UIDatepicker?

Comment: For two, definitely. Even for one.